# How to use SimpleIntegerProperty in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

I tried to populate a `tableView`, I followed the tutorial given in docs.oracle, but in my table there are `Integer` fields, so I do the same thing to add them.

The code in the information class (like `Person` class):

```html
private SimpleIntegerProperty gel;

public int getGel() {
    return gel.get();
}

public void setGel(int pop) {
    gel.set(pop);
}
```

The code in the `Main` class:

```html
TableColumn gel = new TableColumn("Gel");
gel.setMinWidth(100);
gel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Information, Integer>("gel"));
gel.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

gel.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Information, Integer>>() {
    
    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Information, Integer> t) {
        ((Information) t.getTableView().getItems()
            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
            .setGel(t.getNewValue());
    }
});
```

but I have errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
   at javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter.toString(DefaultStringConverter.java:34)
   at javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.getItemText(CellUtils.java:100)
   at javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.updateItem(CellUtils.java:201)
   at javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell.updateItem(TextFieldTableCell.java:204)
```

Comment: Could you be more precise about the errors you get?  Compile, runtime errors?  Which one?

Comment: Please, don't post the error as a new answer. Instead, edit your question (and remove the answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your cell factory.

`TableColumn` should be typed to `TableColumn<Information, Integer>`. Then you will see an error here:

```
gel.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

(the same error you have on runtime). The reason is the static callback `forTableColumn` is only for `TableColumn`of type String.

For other types you have to provide a custom string converter. This will solve your problems:

```
    gel.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Integer>(){

        @Override
        public String toString(Integer object) {
            return object.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Integer fromString(String string) {
            return Integer.parseInt(string);
        }

    }));
```