# Fixing setCellFactory in javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have problem with to set a `setCellFactory` column.
My code looks like this:

```
@FXML
private void EditStudentMarkAction(Integer idUser){       
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Marks> lista = null;
    String path = "http://localhost:8080/Server/source/users/"+idUser+"/marks";

    try {
        lista = mapper.readValue(new URL(path), new TypeReference<List<Marks>>(){});
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    ObservableList<Marks> lis = FXCollections.observableArrayList(lista);        

    columnFirst.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getTest().getTitle()));
    columnSecond.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Marks,String>("date"));       
    columnThird.setEditable(true);
    columnThird.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Marks,String>("mark"));        
    columnThird.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());         
    columnThird.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Marks, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Marks, String> t) {
                ((Marks) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setMark(Float.parseFloat(t.getNewValue()));
            }
        }
    );
    tableEdit.getColumns().setAll(columnFirst,columnSecond,columnThird);
    tableEdit.setItems(lis);      
}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String

When I comments line:

```
columnThird.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

That's my code works, but I can't to edit a row.

So I must translate Float to String in method setCellFactory something like this [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468546/how-to-use-simpleintegerproperty-in-javafx) yes? but I must change Integer to Float?

I added the following code, but still no work and do not build program:

```
columnThird.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Float>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Float t) {
            return t.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Float fromString(String string) {
            return Float.parseFloat(string);
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Which line of code does the stack trace report as the cause of the error?  You may wish to edit the question to provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that potential answerers may more easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: What is the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature#Java_2) of the Marks.setMark method?

Comment: Update main post.     `public float getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(float mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }`

Comment: This is really easier with an mcve, but some guesses: `new PropertyValueFactory<Marks,String>("mark")` isn't going to work because getMark returns a float and not String, it should be `new PropertyValueFactory<Marks,Float>("mark")`.  Also, columnThird may be defined incorrectly, it should be a `TableColumn<Marks,Float>` and you might have defined it as a `TableColumn<Marks,String>`.  If you want to keep it as a String column, you need to change use a custom cellValueFactory (not a PropertyValueFactory) which converts the float value to a String.

Comment: @jewelsea - I changed a String to Float and work fine. Thank you so much.